# Google Analytics In-Page Script Fails To Load

Tags: google-analytics, http-status-code-302

The following link when opened in my chrome results in an infinite loop of 302 redirects which lead to the 'ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS' error:
https://analytics.google.com/analytics/web/inpage/pub/inpage.js?prefix=analytics

This link is loaded when trying to open the google analytics in-page analytics. It does not matter if I turn off the shield sign or open in full screen or whatever, there is always this infinite 302 redirects loop.

I read somewhere that maybe changing the google analytics tracker domain in my script will help but it did not help.

Also tried to clear browser data and cookies and it did not help.

Anybody encountered this problem and has an idea of how to solve it?

What is opened for you when you open this link? And can you also try opening it while being connected to google analytics account?

This is supposed to be the script that turns the in-page analytics functionality so can anybody who has in-page analytics working, test what happens with this link? or check if using in-page analytics in his page loads this script at all?